# nQSError: 93001 - Can not load library, oracore11.dll, due to, 0xc1

Tags: oracle, obiee, oracleclient

I'm having some issues setting up a new machine with the OBIEE client tools.

I installed Oracle Database Client (12.1.0.2.0) for Microsoft Windows (x64)

And then the Oracle Client Tools version 11.1.1.7.150120

The installs both go okay, and I can open and edit the repository, but when I go to check global consistency I get the following error:

```
Business Model Client:
[nQSError: 93001] Can not load library, oracore11.dll, due to, 0xc1.
0xc1
[nQSError: 23013] An error occurred when extracting the metadata definition for the Attribute '"Client"."dim_project_attributes"."Task ID"'.
```

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle support knowlege base (Doc ID 1948956.1) indicates this might be because you are running a 64bit database client with a 32bit OBI Client Tools.

Did you install the 32 or 64 bit OBI Client Tools?

You may also want to check you have no other Oracle Database Clients installed. One way to do this would be to run `where sqlplus` from a cmd prompt. That will give you a list of client tools in the order they appear in your path. The administration tool will use the one that is listed first.